# Can I add a "tag" column to music files and "fill down" to enter the info for it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I want to add a column to Windows Explorer (in Windows 7) such as "Tag" and then fill in the data for that column by some sort of fill down technique (as in Excel) instead of adding info one file at a time. How can I do this?